# Python Web Scrapping Json.loads()

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to fetch only URL from report by response given in json format using python.

The responses are as below:

```
text = {'result':[{'URL':'/disclosure/listedinfo/announcement/c/new/2022-06-30/600781_20220630_1_Xe2cThkh.pdf<br>/disclosure/listedinfo/announcement/c/new/2022-06-30/600781_20220630_10_u0Egjf03.pdf<br>/disclosure/listedinfo/announcement/c/new/2022-06-30/600781_20220630_2_MnC1FzvY.pdf<br>/disclosure/listedinfo/announcement/c/new/2022-06-30/600781_20220630_3_8APKPJ6E.pdf'}]}
```

I would need to add this url text to fetched url: `'http://static.sse.com.cn'`, I coded a for loop:

```
data = json.loads(text)
for every_report in data['result']:
    pdf_url = 'http://static.sse.com.cn' + every_report['URL']
    print(pdf_url)
```

But this is the result I get, only able to fetch the first URL and add the url text I wanted.

```
http://static.sse.com.cn/disclosure/listedinfo/announcement/c/new/2022-06-30/600532_20220630_6_Y2pswtvy.pdf<br>/disclosure/listedinfo/announcement/c/new/2022-06-30/600532_20220630_10_GBwvYOfG.pdf<br>/disclosure/listedinfo/announcement/c/new/2022-06-30/600532_20220630_11_2LvtFNYz.pdf<br>
```

What should I do to get all the URL and add text I want, thank youu.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is ? You say you want to concat the 2 url parts, that seems fine. Maybe share the expected "thing"

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the string value of `URL` key contains `<br>`. You have to remove it first before constructing the full URL.

```py
for every_report in text['result']:
    urls = every_report['URL'].split('<br>')
    pdf_urls = ['http://static.sse.com.cn' + url for url in urls]
    print(pdf_urls)
```

Comment: ahh nowonder, its too long and i never notice it, thank youu very much